# How can I subset for a row that has a target value within a group, and if there are none, subset for a different row within the same group?

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a grouped dataframe so that I end up with one row for each group. For each group, I would like to subset a row if it has a specific value, but if no such row exists, then I would subset an alternative row.

The data is grouped by year and season, and I would like to subset a row with `Month == 2` from the Season 1 group, a row with `Month == 4` from Season 2, a row with `Month == 8` from Season 3, and a row with `Month == 10` from Season 4.

If there is no row with the requirements, then the row in the season group with the largest `value` would be subset. For example, of rows 4 and 5, row 4 would be subset.

```
Year Season Month value 
2012 1      1     3.4 
2012 1      2     6.1 
2012 1      3     9.0 
2012 2      5     4.4 
2012 2      6     1.2 
2012 3      8     4.9 
2012 4      10    2.7 
2013 1      3     8.3 
2013 1      3     2.4 
2013 2      4     7.0 
2013 3      7     12.1 
2013 3      8     5.7 
2013 4      10    6.3 
2013 4      11    3.3
```

The desired output is:

```
Year Season Month value 
2012 1      2     6.1 
2012 2      5     4.4 
2012 3      8     4.9 
2012 4      10    2.7 
2013 1      3     8.3 
2013 2      4     7.0 
2013 3      8     5.7 
2013 4      10    6.3
```

I've tried the following code but couldn't figure out how to include my alternative requirement in the same bit of code (which I think would need an `if` and `else if`?)

```
df %>%
  group_by(Year, Season) %>%
  slice(which(Month == 2 | Month == 4 | Month == 8 | Month == 10))
  #slice(which.max(value)) #selects row with largest value in each group
```

Comment: INstead of `==`, use `%in%` for multiple elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
data %>%
  mutate(cond = case_when(
    Season == 1 & Month == 2 ~ 1,
    Season == 2 & Month == 4 ~ 1,
    Season == 3 & Month == 8 ~ 1,
    Season == 4 & Month == 10 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )) %>%
  group_by(Year, Season) %>%
  arrange(desc(cond), desc(Value)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Yes, this worked! Glad to have learned about `case_when()` :)